# problems with tomcat 8 on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have this problem with tomcat on eclipse. I have already searched on internet but noting has changed. Can you help me please?

this is the code displayed on the console:

```
   lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:label-editor' did not find a matching property.
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Server built:          Jul 1 2015 20:19:55 UTC
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Server number:         8.0.24.0
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: OS Name:               Windows 7
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: OS Version:            6.1
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Architecture:          x86
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b15
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\lbastelli\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\lbastelli\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\lbastelli\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\endorsed
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFORMAZIONI: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2012\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\eclipse;;.
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFORMAZIONI: Initialization processed in 1833 ms
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFORMAZIONI: Starting service Catalina
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
    INFORMAZIONI: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [908] milliseconds.
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:43 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFORMAZIONI: Server startup in 7848 ms
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
    GRAVE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
    java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:659)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

    lug 13, 2015 1:21:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFORMAZIONI: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFORMAZIONI: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFORMAZIONI: Stopping service Catalina
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:51 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
    AVVERTENZA: The web application [label-editor] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:51 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
    GRAVE: The web application [label-editor] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap] (value [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap@39be91]) and a value of type [java.util.Hashtable] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFORMAZIONI: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFORMAZIONI: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFORMAZIONI: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    lug 13, 2015 1:21:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFORMAZIONI: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

some ideas?

I have already tryed to change the admin port of tomcat but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

One Tomcat instance is already started and the server port is busy.

Try:

- close eclipse
- kill any Tomcat processes from the task manager
- restart eclipse
- start Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

When you open sockets for network communication you need to pass two parameters address and port. The address specifies which network interfaces to use. Commonly it is set to either localhost (127.0.0.1) or 0.0.0.0 (which means all available addresses).

The error `Cannot assign requested address` means that you try to open socket on a wrong address. If only your Tomcat configuration would be wrong, then I think that the message would be different, so check your hosts file (C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts on Windows). See if it does not contain any entries like `10.31.1.1 localhost` or similar.

By default, Tomcat uses "localhost", so these entries are first suspect.

Comment: it says that it's fine but when i go to the browser it returns an error